# How to differentiate with respect to a matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, derivative, matrix-calculus

How can I differentiate the following by $\mathbf{W}$ ?

\begin{equation}
      \mathbf{Y} = (\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{x} + b)^2
\end{equation}

Where $\mathbf{W} \in \mathcal{R}^{d\times D}$ and $\mathbf(x)\in \mathcal{R}^{d\times 1}$

How to calculate $\partial \mathbf{Y}/\partial \mathbf{W}$ ?

Comment: Can you explain what is the context? In this kind of equations you usually differentiate the vector, and the matrix is constant.

Comment: $\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{x} + b$ does not make any sense. You cannot add a column vector to a scalar.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo from context it is clear that b is a column vector that they forgot to bold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Matrix calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) is used in such cases. Your equation looks like it's from OLS (least squares) theory. In those you differentiate by *vector* $x$ some quadratic forms like $\frac{\partial (x'A'Ax)}{\partial x}$. Look up relevant formulae in my link above.

If you really are up to differentiating by *matrices* not vectors, you'll end up with *tensors*. Tensors are fun, but so far I haven't seem them used a lot in statistics. They're ubiquitous in physics, btw. Again, follow the link I gave.